# Strength Based Search Multiple Terms

Tags: c#, linq, search, nhibernate

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a "strength based search" using multiple fields/terms. For example:

*Searching:*

- Number Of Legs: 4
- Has Fur: True
- Has Hooves: True
- Keywords: Moo

*Results:*

- [High] Cow
- [Medium] Cat
- [Medium] Dog
- [Low] Hairless Mole-rat
- [No Match] Bird

It may be worth mentioning that the criteria in my actual model is somewhat weighted, related, and structured.

My language of choice is C#.NET, and I'm using LINQ + Fluent NHibernate. I have been playing around with a few different ways to implement this, but most feel clunky. Currently, the DB I'm using has over 100,000 "Animals", and they can be searched on against ~15 fields.

**Questions:**

Does this kind of search have a name?

Are there best practices or techniques that I should be aware of while trying to implement this?

What are some high performance ways to implement a search like this? Psuedo code and general logic appreciated just as much as code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177753/search-ranking-relevance-algorithms

Comment: You could use SQL Server's full text search to generate a relevancy score on keyword(s), and merge that with your booleans to generate a composite relevancy score.  That should make your searches fairly quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're speaking about a "[weighted term query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142577(v=sql.105).aspx)".

Since you're already using LINQ and I assume MSSQL, your quickest solution is probably to write a stored procedure (that you will ultimately call with LINQ) which uses full-text search functions (`CONTAINSTABLE` and `ISABOUT`) to "rank" results the way you desire.

---

*If you expect heavy search traffic or your ranking requirements get much more complex, or your collection grows significantly you should consider breaking this functionality out into a search engine like Solr or Elasticsearch.*